# SQL multiple queries for WHERE comparator

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to write a MySQL query that will select results from `TABLE2` based on the result from query to `TABLE1`. Something like this:

```
SELECT route_id FROM trips WHERE trip_id = 
SELECT trip_id  FROM stop_times WHERE 
stop_id=<ID GOES HERE> LIMIT 1
```

but this doesn't work so I tried this:

```
SELECT route_id FROM trips WHERE trip_id 
INNER JOIN(
SELECT trip_id  FROM stop_times WHERE stop_id=<ID GOES HERE> LIMIT 1
)
```

and it also doesn't work. I'm getting this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN(SELECT trip_id  FROM stop_times WHERE stop_id="16817" LIMIT 1)
LIMIT 0' at line 1
```

Comment: Put the internal `SELECT` inside parentheses, and please format it better so we can read it more easily.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original query should be written like this:

```
SELECT t.route_id
FROM trips t
WHERE t.trip_id = (SELECT st.trip_id
                   FROM stop_times st
                   WHERE st.stop_id = <ID GOES HERE>
                   LIMIT 1
                  );
```

I think this would more normally be written as:

```
SELECT t.route_id
FROM stop_times st JOIN
     trips t
     ON t.trip_id = st.trip_id
WHERE st.stop_id = <ID GOES HERE>
LIMIT 1;
```

This assumes that you want one row returned.

Answer (score 0):

your subquery should be:

```
SELECT route_id 
FROM trips 
WHERE trips.trip_id =
( 
    SELECT stop_times.trip_id  
    FROM stop_times 
    WHERE stop_id = <ID GOES HERE> 
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

```
SELECT route_id FROM trips WHERE trip_id in (SELECT trip_id  FROM stop_times WHERE stop_id=<ID GOES HERE> LIMIT 1)
```

or the much easier:

```
select t.route_id from trips t, stop_times s where t.trip_id = s.trip_id and s.stop_id= <ID GOES HERE> LIMIT 1
```